# Find the biggest single number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `number` as follows:

```
num
---
8
8
3
3
1
6
4
```

I want to find out the biggest number which only appear once. I've this query:

```
select max(num) from number group by num having count(*)=1
```

It returns:

```
{"headers": ["max(num)"], "values": [[1], [4], [6]]}
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
 select max(num) from number group by num having count(*)=1
```

You are using group by num  so the max(num) for group by num is like num

so you get each num with  count(*)  =1

If you need the max  you should use

```
select max(num) from
( select num
from number 
group by num
having count(*) = 1   ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions, such as `max()` are applied to each group as determined by the `group by` clause. Since you are grouping the numbers by their value, the query is finding the max in each group, which just happens to be the same number.

To solve this, you could use subqueries, or order in a descending way while limiting the no of rows to 1.

Comment: Perfect. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(num)
FROM   number
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num) = 1
ORDER BY num DESC
```

I hope I have helped.